# Alternative to volatile?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, c99, volatile

I'm using a lot of `volatile` variables in my embedded firmware, but most of the time there is only one point in a function where I need to be sure the value is recent (at the start). But the rest of the function is referring to the same variable-name, and the value can be changed in the mean time, producing very unexpected code flow / results. I know this can be solved by using a temporary variable inside the function, but I was looking for a better solution.

Now I was wondering, instead of marking the whole variable as `volatile`, is there a way I could instruct the compiler (gcc) with a special keyword that I want to read the variable as if it was marked volatile, so I can use that keyword only once at the beginning of the function?

Comment: In what way could a solution be better than using a temporary variable? That seems like the obvious, perfect solution.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have to modify every function that is using those  volatile variabeles to 'cache' it at the start of the function, and make sure all code is referring to the temporary variabele instead of the real one. If I could remove the 'volatile' keyword completely, all I have to do is find the locations where a volatile read is actually needed, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Leave the accesses alone. Change the name of the volatile variables.

Comment: please provide an example.

Comment: I am not sure that use of a compiler specific extension could be construed as a *"better solution"*, the best (and entirely adequate) solution is the one you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about the scenario - if it's that you want *one particular access* to a variable to be treated as `volatile`, use

```
dest = *(volatile TYPE *)&src;
```

where TYPE is the type of `src`.  You may also need

```
asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");
```

in carefully controlled locations, to prevent the compiler from moving loads/stores of other memory locations across the volatile read.

Also investigate C11's `_Atomic` types. (I'm not sure if GCC supports these yet.)

Comment: Yes, I want one particular access to a variable to be treated as volatile.

Comment: I don't think this will work, at least, it's not guaranteed to. If the final write is not done through `volatile`, the value he needs may not be in memory yet. It could be, for example, cached in a register.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's one of the risks associated with treating some but not all of the accesses to a variable as `volatile`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is in memory and your embedded system supports it you could use memory barriers. To make sure that nothing accesses the memory while you are reading the value out.